# Static files not found - Deploying Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I am trying to deploy a Django site on Heroku, but I'm running into problems getting the app to locate my static files.  I have used `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect my static files into a staticfiles folder, but my app still doesn't seem to be able to find them.  I continue to get errors like this in my log:

[image]

I'm not sure if I am referencing the paths properly.  The path's that are set to images/stylesheets/scripts in the code are using the path to the original static folder used in development.  Do I have to rewrite all of those paths to point to the new staticfiles folder I created with the `collectstatic` command, or is there some other issue that could be causing this?

My settings.py looks like this:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['www.tomdeldridge.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tomdeldridge.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['tomdeldridge/templates/tomdeldridge/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tomdeldridge.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__),
        'static',
    ),
)

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My wsgi.py file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tomdeldridge.settings")
```

My directory structure:

[image]

The images I'm trying to reference in my template definitely exist (they work fine when I run the app locally.) I reference them like this:

`{% static 'tomdeldridge/images/computer-2.png' %}`

Do I have to use a server like nginx to serve static files in deployment?  I am totally lost on where to go from here, and I'm not really sure why it's necessary to reconfigure the entire static file structure just to deploy.

Comment: You haven't shown any of the relevant code: the settings, or how you're referencing the images in the template.

Comment: That's not quite enough of the directory structure; where is settings.py in relation to static? And also show the template where you're using the static files.

Comment: Fair enough.  I added in an image of the whole directory structure, and an example of code I use to reference images in the template.  Anything else that would be helpful?

Comment: Do you use django built-in server, gunicorn, uWSGI?

Comment: I use gunicorn as my server

Answer (score 1):

Install `dj-static` package

```
$ pip install dj-static
```

Configure your static assets in `settings.py`:

```
DEBUG = False
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then, update your `wsgi.py` file to use dj-static:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tomdeldridge.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Comment: My settings.py, and wsgi.py look exactly like you said, and I installed dj_static successfully, and pushed the updated git repository, but I keep getting the same error saying the path to the static files can't be found.

Comment: I updated the question with complete `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` code.

Comment: Move `os.environ.setdefault...` to the top.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to fix the issue.